# Intellij and maven templating plugin: how to reference java-templates

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I want to use the [Templating Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/index.html) in my project, but I don't understand where to put my sources. The plugin docs specify:

```
${basedir}/src/main/java-templates
```

but Intellij does not recognize this as a sources folder, and therefore won't allow me to create classes in it. If I make it a sources folder manually, then I run into the issue that I can't reference my classes from the `src/main/java` folder.

Where should I put the classes to be fitered, or how do I configure Intellij to work with the Templating Plugin?

Comment: Vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CrazyCoder answered my question. This feature has just not been implemented yet in Intellij.